# Missing OpenColorIO.dll for game engine executable

Tags: game-engine, export, windows

I saved my blend file as Game Engine Runtime in a Windows 7 system. Now I have an executable file. The file works perfectly fine on my current computer but when I open that file on another computer (also Windows 7), it gives me an error that says "OpenColorIO.dll is missing"

So my question is, what should I do to resolve the error? I'm not really familiar with dlls and what to do with it.

Also, will the .exe file run on a computer that doesn't have Blender installed?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Making_exe

Answer (score 2):

Probably all the dlls are mimssing. When you export your file as a game executable, you should check the box "Copy dlls".
Anyway, check it was actually made : in the chosen directory, you should find :
- the .exe file
- a folder labeled according to your blender version
- all the required dlls
To get your exe running on a computer without blender, you should send all these files.